# Randomize distribution of objects (CO2 molecules) in space

Tags: particles, hair, emission

I'm producing kind of an environment full of CO2 molecules, the idea is to randomize the CO2 molecules around a porous sphere,  however when I do the particle system, they're distributed following straight lines, extremely organized, which is very unrealistic.

[image]

Any idea how can I randomize them?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very easy way to do this with a nice animation is geometry nodes.

So just add a cube, subdivide it a few times, and scale it big enough.

Then add the geometry nodes modifier to it.

Add this node tree to it:

[image]

So you get this:

[image]

and you can animate the two factors and you will get this:

[image]

I just used a torus for your "co2" -> just replace this with your co2.

[image]

Comment: Wow, great work. Thanks a lot @Chris. I will try that. It could be cool to have in the future, a randomize option in the particle-system.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 5):

Unless I'm missing something, particle emission from volume does what you want?

[image]

(The cube is the emitter)

Comment: Exactly. As you just showed, randomized particles mimicking CO2 molecules.